# Downloading stock price data using IBpy

Tags: python, ibpy

I adapted the following code from http://godelsmarket.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/non-gui-ib-historical-data-downloader.html. I wanted to download MMM's price data for 20151001.

```
from time import sleep, strftime, localtime  
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract  
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message  

new_symbolinput = ['MMM']  
newDataList = []  
dataDownload = []  

def historical_data_handler(msg):  
 global newDataList  
 #print msg.reqId, msg.date, msg.open, msg.high, msg.low, msg.close, msg.volume  
 if ('finished' in str(msg.date)) == False:  
   new_symbol = new_symbolinput[msg.reqId]  
   dataStr = '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (new_symbol, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(int(msg.date))), msg.open, msg.high, msg.low, msg.close, msg.volume)  
   newDataList = newDataList + [dataStr]  
 else:  
   new_symbol = new_symbolinput[msg.reqId]  
   filename = 'minutetrades' + new_symbol + '.csv'  
   csvfile = open('csv_day_test/' + filename,'wb')  
   for item in newDataList:  
     csvfile.write('%s \n' % item)  
   csvfile.close()  
   newDataList = []  
   global dataDownload  
   dataDownload.append(new_symbol)  

con = ibConnection()  
con.register(historical_data_handler, message.historicalData)  
print(con.connect())

symbol_id = 0  
for i in new_symbolinput:  
 print(i)
 qqq = Contract()  
 qqq.m_symbol = i  
 qqq.m_secType = 'STK'  
 qqq.m_exchange = 'SMART'  
 qqq.m_currency = 'USD'  
 con.reqHistoricalData(symbol_id, qqq, '20151001', '1 D', '1 min', 'TRADES', 1, 2)  

 symbol_id = symbol_id + 1  
 sleep(0.5)  

print (dataDownload)
```

However, the output I got yields an empty data list at the end:

```
Server Version: 68
TWS Time at connection:20151004 09:30:11 EST
True
MMM
[]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should register a handler for errors, or else one for all other messages.

```
def watchAll(msg):
    print(msg)
​
con = ibConnection()  
con.registerAll(watchAll)
con.unregister(watchAll, message.historicalData)
con.register(historical_data_handler, message.historicalData)
```

Then you'd get an error saying your date time format is wrong.  Change it to
`20151001 00:00:00`.  You can add a time zone.

`csvfile.write('%s \n' % item)` won't work in python3 use `csvfile.write(bytes('%s \n' % item,'UTF-8'))` and make sure you create the directory.  But this binary writing needs to be looked at by a pythonista.

You changed the sleep to 0.5 from 10.  It will work for you because you just want one symbol but the 10 was probably to eliminate pacing errors.  You have a limit to much much data you can ask for every minute.

The var name qqq is strange.  It must have been copied from an example where someone downloaded symbol qqq.  You should rename it to something like `contract`.

Comment: Here is what I received: Server Version: 68
TWS Time at connection:20151004 11:00:44 EST
True
MMM
<managedAccounts accountsList=DU15058>
<nextValidId orderId=1>
<error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:ibdemo>
<error id=-1, errorCode=2107, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.demohmds>
<error id=-1, errorCode=2106, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:demohmds>
<error id=0, errorCode=162, errorMsg=Historical Market Data Service error message:Starting time must occur before ending time>
[]

Comment: Maybe try an earlier date.  The date I posted worked for me and it downloaded all data for 2015-09-30.

Comment: I tried 20151001, it said <error id=-1, errorCode=2107, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.demohmds>. Seems like historical market data service is not available for demos?

Comment: Even though it's an error code, it's just informational.  I get the same message but not demohmds.  I'll try with the demo account.

Comment: I get <error id=0, errorCode=162, errorMsg=Historical Market Data Service error message:HMDS query returned no data: SPY@SMART Trades>  So it works but no data from the demo account.

Comment: oh so it seems like we can't download historical data using the demo account?